# Search a word in System.Collections.Hashtable

Tags: c#, .net

I have an issue in in .net project. I am using System.Collections.Hashtable to store values  and add key value like

"putreturnsbetweenparagraphs"

and I want to search word "between" on that key value.

Now I am using

```
//Declare hash table
System.Collections.Hashtable _Index;

//add values to hashtable
_Index.Add("putreturnsbetweenparagraphs",theword );

//search section
string searchWord="between";
            if (_Index.ContainsKey(searchWord))
            {    
               //code
            }
```

Any idea about this ?

Comment: are you going to add multiple keys in he hash-table and then you want to search?

Comment: Why do you have four c# tags? There's nothing version-specific about your question (there isn't really even anything C#-specific), and even if there were I'd expect you to add *one* single tag specifying the version. There's also nothing asp.net-specific about the question. It's really just .NET.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
string value = (string)_Index.Cast<System.Collections.DictionaryEntry>()
                             .First(x => (x.Key as string).Contains(searchWord))
                             .Value;
```

Comment: Thanks @L.B for a new thread. Now I am using 

`foreach (DictionaryEntry Item in _Index)
{
if (Item.Key.ToString().Contains(searchWord))
{
 //code
}
}`

Answer (score 3):

For a start, unless you're *really* using .NET 1.1, you should look at using `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` instead of the non-generic `Hashtable`.

Beyond that though, a straight key/value map isn't going to help you much. Basically you either need to change your data structure somehow, or iterate over *all* the keys in the collection, and check whether *any* of them contains the target string. You'd effectively be treating the map as a sequence of key/value pairs - the fast lookup given by hashing would be irrelevant, as it's only useful when performing an equality lookup.